# How can I Handle user plugins in my types?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, records

I'm writing a modular and extensible text editor in Haskell and I'd like to implement plugins in such a way: The writer of the plugin provides a single function that looks something like this:

```
handleEvent :: (PluginState, EditorState) -> Event -> (PluginState, EditorState)
```

As each event occurs the plugin can use the current editor state and customized chunk of its own state to calculate a new editor state and new plugin state. Of course each Plugin is going to have a different Type for the Plugin state, so I'm getting stuck on how I can integrate this into my system in a general way.

How can I write something vaguely like this:

```
type Plugin = (PluginState, EditorState) -> Event -> (PluginState, EditorState)
data MyEditor = MyEditor EditorState [Plugin] [PluginState]
```

When PluginState isn't a concrete type?

TLDR; How can I store a map of values with non-concrete types in an accessible way without baking in every plugin's state-type into my global state? I'm okay with re-compiling the editor when a new plugin is added.

Thanks! I'm really stuck on this one :/

If you need any clarification please just ask!

Comment: A starting point for this would be to look up how GHC handles plugins and how Yi handles configuration. Both take a partial recompile approach I think...

Comment: Sounds like a case for https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of course each Plugin is going to have a different Type for the Plugin state, so I'm getting stuck on how I can integrate this into my system in a general way.

Perhaps you could use an [existential type](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#existentially-quantified-data-constructors) to hide the plugin state, something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Plugin = forall ps. Plugin { 
       currentState :: ps
    ,  transition :: ps -> EditorState -> Event -> (ps, EditorState) 
    }

handleEvent :: Plugin -> EditorState -> Event -> (Plugin,EditorState)
handleEvent (Plugin ps t) es e =
    let (ps',es') = t ps es e
    in  (Plugin ps' t,es')
```

Now each plugin is of the same type, and yet different plugin values can have internal states of different types:

```
charPlugin :: Plugin
charPlugin = Plugin 'a' (\ps es e -> (succ ps,es))

intPlugin :: Plugin
intPlugin = Plugin (1::Int) (\ps es e -> (succ ps,es))
```

(I took inspiration from the [`Fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.2.1/docs/Control-Foldl.html#t:Fold) type from the *foldl* package, which uses existentials in a similar way.)

You can now have a list of plugins:

```
plugins :: [Plugin]
plugins = [charPlugin,intPlugin]
```

A possible evolution of the design would be to constrain the internal states to be instances of some typeclass:

```
data Plugin = forall ps. Show ps => Plugin { 
       currentState :: ps
    ,  transition :: ps -> EditorState -> Event -> (ps, EditorState) 
    }
```

---

I suspect a `Monoid` instance could be defined for the `Plugin` type.

Also, we could think of explicitly parameterizing `Plugin` on the type of events it accepts, like

```
data Plugin e = ...
```

In that case Plugin could be made an instance of [`Contravariant`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.4/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#t:Contravariant) and perhaps [`Divisible`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.4/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Divisible.html#t:Divisible) as well.

And if we go wild and parameterize on the editor state

```
data Plugin es e = ...
```

then perhaps we could find a way to "zoom" a given plugin to work in a more general state than the one for which it was defined.

Comment: It's a bit awkward to work with when applying (I have to unpack the transition function, apply it, then repack the state AND the transition function back up into a new Plugin to be returned), but aside from that it works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Penner The packing-unpacking can be handled by a single function like `handleEvent`, though. Also, the `Plugin` type should have strict fields to avoid space leaks.