# Allowing agents to have their internal state

Tags: haskell, state

I am writing a game in Haskell in which the player and the AI are taking some actions in turns. Until now, the AIs worked by generating actions using all the information about the game, i.e they were functions of the form `GameHistory -> GameState -> Action`.

This way these functions generate some information they need from the history each time they are called. It would be a lot easier to write AIs if they could have some kind of "internal state" which persists between their turns (i.e. calls to the corresponding function). How could one implement something like that? (By the way, I should also take into account that internal states of different kinds of AIs could have different types.)

Comment: I'm finding this question too broad, I can't really give you an answer more specific than "Use the state monad". If you could [edit] your question to provide some actual code then we could probably be more helpful.

Comment: @aclow Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698396/how-can-i-handle-user-plugins-in-my-types/

Comment: @danidiaz Thanks, that looks like what I am looking for. I will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for might be something like:

```
newtype AI = AI { runAI :: GameState -> (AI, Action) }
```

i.e. you'll return your actor's new state along with the action. You might make use of the `State` monad here. You might also be interested in reading about automata. If you need to serialize your `AI` (to store it in a database, say) then you might need to do something different.